# The cookies uploaded by the Fetch API are incomplete

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch

There is a `Cookie` in the request header of the request initiated by calling fetch api. Yes, I have set `credentials:"include"`.

The problem is that the cookies only contains 'jsessionid'. But actually there is a cookie named token, which I set on the server side by `response.addCookie(new Cookie("token",token));`.

I use Chrome's F12 and find that the cookie named 'token' normally exists in cookies, but it is not in the cookie in the request header of the request initiated by fetch.

what should I do to ask the Fetch Api to bring it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the domain and path of the cookie? What URL is fetch making the request to?

Comment: @Quentin Thank you very much! The problem is in the backend. I added setPath ("/") to the cookie object and solved the problem. Could you answer the problem so I can close this problem? Thanks.